# Why use UseCases? Android Jetpack is not mentioning UseCases in the docs

Tags: android, mvvm, android-architecture-components, android-jetpack, clean-architecture

Is it really necessary to use UseCases in my android Clean Architecture?

In the Android Jetpack [documentation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/docs/guide) they are not mentioning it.
They are accessing the repository directly from the ViewModels.

Isn't that a better option? Isn't the UseCase code not just making it unnecessarily more difficult to adjust the code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to strictly follow Uncle Bob's clean architecture then you should use UseCases.

> They are accessing the repository directly from the ViewModels. Isn't that a better option?

It depends, greatly, the clean architecture makes testing super easy, also makes you think more architecturally before you implement things and makes you not to make compromises a.k.a. *adjusting code*, and it follows SOLID principles which are just great.

On the other hand, it's much harder to setup project and sometimes it feels like you are overengineering it

But after setting it up you will see improvement in maintainability and also scalability.

I think that it's great to know what clean architecture is and take what suits your needs.

This is great resource if you want to learn more about clean architecture https://caster.io/courses/android-clean-architecture and how it fits android.

Comment: the link mentioned in the end throws 404: NOT_FOUND

Answer (score 4):

Well I think it's really not necessary to use `UseCases`, especially if you are not familiar with them. `UseCases` are just an architectural pattern for creating a more scalable project and to reuse code.

I am personally using `UseCases` where I see that it makes sense. For example in our project we have the `View`, `ViewModel` and `Repository`. Two common cases to use a `UseCase` would be if

**1)** Two `ViewModel` has a common logic of processing data from the `Repository`. That could go into a `UseCase` (But not necessarily, you can create a smaller `VM` for just that)

**2)** You want to include a plus layer between the `Repository` and `ViewModel`, because you need that layer to handle some extra logic, that is out of the purpose of the `Repository` and/or `ViewModel`. For example neither the `Repository` nor the `ViewModel` should solve scheduling problems. (A problem like, if you have cache get the data on the **MainThread**, if not switch to a background thread.)

So in conclusion, nothing related to architecture is necessary. You shouldn't force something on your project, architectural patterns are there only to make your application easier to modify, scale, work with.